# Can't get Excel to open a Word document

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble getting Excel to open a Word document, I keep getting runtime error 5174. I can't seem to find the problem, and the path seems to be correct.

The code line erroring out is documents.open line, in the code below:

```
'Instantiate Word and open the "Transfer price" document.
Set wdApp = New Word.Application
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\SIDVI\Desktop" & "\" & "stWordDocument")
```

Comment: Is `stWordDocument` the actual name of the file (doesn't it have a `.docx` extension?), or is that the name of a variable which contains the name of the file?

Comment: No it is not, the file name is contained in a string called stWordDocument and it has a .docx extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement to open the file should be:

```
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\SIDVI\Desktop\" & stWordDocument)
```

By placing `stWordDocument` in double-quotation marks, you were making it a String literal instead of a variable, and therefore you were trying to open the actual file called `"C:\Users\SIDVI\Desktop\stWordDocument"`.